# devExpress dxSelectBox dataSource Angular2+

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, devexpress

I try to create dxForm with dxi-item which will fill up dxSelectBox:

First example deos not work, it's work only if I set items as string[] array, but object[] array deos not work please help? Also I try to set dataSource in editorOptions.

example:

```
<dxi-item [label]="{text: 'Test'}" editorType="dxSelectBox" [editorOptions]="{ dataSource:testList, items:testList, displayExpr:'name', valueExpr:'id', placeholder:'Select Test' }">
 <dxi-validation-rule type="required" message="Test is required"></dxi-validation-rule>
</dxi-item>
```

Even I set dataSource but no luck? Second example with object[] array works good but I want to use dxi-item directive:

```
<div class="dx-field">
        <div class="dx-field-label">Test usage</div>
        <div class="dx-field-value">
            <dx-select-box
                [dataSource]="testList"
                displayExpr="name"
                valueExpr="id"
                [value]=""
            ></dx-select-box>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think setting the "items" option overrides records from your data source. In your second snippet, you are not assigning items. Try to remove this binding.

Comment: Second snippet is ok and it works but first one does not work even I remove items from editorOptions.

Comment: Then, would you clarify how the "testList" array looks like?

Comment: Problem was http async call, so component is inited and I got response one second later and I change fieldData array with new array, actually I need push data from response array to fieldData array.

Answer (score 2):

Bind in this way so that Angular binding works:

```
<dxi-item [label]="{text: 'Test'}" editorType="dxSelectBox" [editorOptions]="selectBoxOptions">
 <dxi-validation-rule type="required" message="Test is required"></dxi-validation-rule>
</dxi-item>


selectBoxOptions = { dataSource:[], displayExpr:'name', valueExpr:'id', placeholder:'Select Test' };

http.get(URL).then(data => {
    this.selectBoxOptions = { dataSource:data, displayExpr:'name', valueExpr:'id', placeholder:'Select Test' }
});
```